# Tensorflow getting data into it (SVHN)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

i sucessfully installed tensorflow and followed the easy tutorial on the MNIST data.
now i wanna build models to train on the SVHN data. Unfortunately i cannot find anywhere how i can get the data into the model.
Basically the first step of every model.
the data is saved in a dict, with the keys "X" for the parameters and 'y' for the labels.
the shapes are as follows:

print traindata['X'].shape

(32, 32, 3, 73257)

print traindata['y'].shape

(73257, 1)

Can anyone give me a tip or a link how to get this successfully into tensorflow?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The SVNH's `digitStruct.mat` is in matlab's file format, so you should convert it.

Here is a code to covert the `digitStruct.mat` to json, or you can use `scipy.io.loadmat`

```python
# coding: utf-8
# SVHN extracts data from the digitStruct.mat full numbers files.  The data can be downloaded
# the Street View House Number (SVHN)  web site: http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers.
#
# This is an A2iA tweak (YG -9 Jan 2014) of the script found here :
# http://blog.grimwisdom.com/python/street-view-house-numbers-svhn-and-octave
#
# The digitStruct.mat files in the full numbers tars (train.tar.gz, test.tar.gz, and extra.tar.gz)
# are only compatible with matlab.  This Python program can be run at the command line and will generate
# a json version of the dataset.
#
# Command line usage:
#       SVHN_dataextract.py [-f input] [-o output_without_extension]
#    >  python SVHN_dataextract.py -f digitStruct.mat -o digitStruct
#
# Issues:
#    The alibility to split in several files has been removed from the original
#    script.
#

import tqdm
import h5py
import optparse
from json import JSONEncoder

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", dest="fin", help="Matlab full number SVHN input file", default="digitStruct.mat")
parser.add_option("-o", dest="filePrefix", help="name for the json output file", default="digitStruct")
options, args = parser.parse_args()

fin = options.fin


# The DigitStructFile is just a wrapper around the h5py data.  It basically references
#    inf:              The input h5 matlab file
#    digitStructName   The h5 ref to all the file names
#    digitStructBbox   The h5 ref to all struc data
class DigitStructFile:
    def __init__(self, inf):
        self.inf = h5py.File(inf, 'r')
        self.digitStructName = self.inf['digitStruct']['name']
        self.digitStructBbox = self.inf['digitStruct']['bbox']

    # getName returns the 'name' string for for the n(th) digitStruct.
    def getName(self, n):
        return ''.join([chr(c[0]) for c in self.inf[self.digitStructName[n][0]].value])

    # bboxHelper handles the coding difference when there is exactly one bbox or an array of bbox.
    def bboxHelper(self, attr):
        if len(attr) > 1:
            attr = [self.inf[attr.value[j].item()].value[0][0] for j in range(len(attr))]
        else:
            attr = [attr.value[0][0]]
        return attr

    # getBbox returns a dict of data for the n(th) bbox.
    def getBbox(self, n):
        bbox = {}
        bb = self.digitStructBbox[n].item()
        bbox['height'] = self.bboxHelper(self.inf[bb]["height"])
        bbox['label'] = self.bboxHelper(self.inf[bb]["label"])
        bbox['left'] = self.bboxHelper(self.inf[bb]["left"])
        bbox['top'] = self.bboxHelper(self.inf[bb]["top"])
        bbox['width'] = self.bboxHelper(self.inf[bb]["width"])
        return bbox

    def getDigitStructure(self, n):
        s = self.getBbox(n)
        s['name'] = self.getName(n)
        return s

    # getAllDigitStructure returns all the digitStruct from the input file.
    def getAllDigitStructure(self):
        print('Starting get all digit structure')
        return [self.getDigitStructure(i) for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(len(self.digitStructName)))]

    # Return a restructured version of the dataset (one structure by boxed digit).
    #
    #   Return a list of such dicts :
    #      'filename' : filename of the samples
    #      'boxes' : list of such dicts (one by digit) :
    #          'label' : 1 to 9 corresponding digits. 10 for digit '0' in image.
    #          'left', 'top' : position of bounding box
    #          'width', 'height' : dimension of bounding box
    #
    # Note: We may turn this to a generator, if memory issues arise.
    def getAllDigitStructure_ByDigit(self):
        pictDat = self.getAllDigitStructure()
        result = []
        structCnt = 1
        print('Starting pack josn dict')
        for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(len(pictDat))):
            item = {'filename': pictDat[i]["name"] }
            figures = []
            for j in range(len(pictDat[i]['height'])):
                figure = dict()
                figure['height'] = pictDat[i]['height'][j]
                figure['label']  = pictDat[i]['label'][j]
                figure['left']   = pictDat[i]['left'][j]
                figure['top']    = pictDat[i]['top'][j]
                figure['width']  = pictDat[i]['width'][j]
                figures.append(figure)
            structCnt += 1
            item['boxes'] = figures
            result.append(item)
        return result


dsf = DigitStructFile(fin)
dataset = dsf.getAllDigitStructure_ByDigit()
fout = open(options.filePrefix + ".json", 'w')
fout.write(JSONEncoder(indent=True).encode(dataset))
fout.close()
```

After that, you should write code to load the data into numpy.

And in my opinion, your task is not load the data into TensorFlow, but load the all the images into numpy. So, you should also use `PIL` library to read the images into numpy format.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good idea is to reshape your data into something like:

print traindata['X'].shape 
(73257, 32*32*3) = (73257, 3072)

I'm new to tensorflow and python too but i think u can do this by using numpy with np.reshape

look at the following documentation :
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Tell me if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow uses this concept where: first, you define a graph; next, you train a graph; lastly, you employ the graph.

At the moment you define the graph, you make placeholders. That are like input nodes for your graph. However, at this time, these variables are "empty" in the sense that they do not relate to your input data.

Both at train-time and test-time, you "feed" your data into the graph by referring to this predefined input nodes.

This concept can be new to you and I recommend you take some tutorials on it. TensorFlow itself has a nice page called "Tensorflow Mechanics 101" and "basic usage". 
If you are more visual, I can recommend the YouTube channel "Dan Does Data" he explores the TensorFlow concepts in a humorous way.

If you are more the person who likes example-code, you can consider [this](http://robromijnders.github.io/tensorflow_basic/) example, where I make a small CNN for MNIST. Have a look at the placeholders "x" and "y_", they are the variables of your interest.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a course that uses this data set. Needed to convert to grayscale and keep the dimension, scale image data to [0,1), change the 10 labels to 0, and moveaxis so the index of the image is first. Ended up doing the stuff below. After that things like: model.fit(xTrain,yTrain, ... ) worked.

```
    xTrain,xTest=np.mean(xTrain0,axis=2,keepdims=True),np.mean(xTest0,axis=2,keepdims=True);
xTrain/=255; xTest/=255
print(f'Min: {xTrain.min()}, Max: {xTrain.max()}')
yTrain[yTrain>9]=0; yTest[yTest>9]=0
print(f'Min: {yTrain.min()}, Max: {yTrain.max()}')
xTrain,xTest=np.moveaxis(xTrain,-1,0),np.moveaxis(xTest,-1,0)
print(xTrain.shape,xTest.shape)
```